# Program breaks when not running with debugger attached

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, opengl

I'm working on a 2D engine, it's written in C++ and I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64 bit.

I use OpenGL for hardware acceleration, and am now experimenting with framebuffers for using textures as canvas. (For things like allowing the user to paint on the screen)

Now this framebuffer works fine, **as long as I start the program with the debugger attached (F5)**

If I start the program from outside the IDE, or start it without the debugger (CTRL+F5), I can't paint to the texture, but get flickering and OpenGL stack underflow errors every frame.

- I really don't know where to start searching for the problem, can you please help me?

Comment: Does your program multithreading?

Comment: First check if you have all .dll in same folder as .exe .. And if so, try changing in project properties (alt+F7) configuration properties-> c/c++ -> code generation and in right menu change runtime library to /MTd

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure, but it could be one of several things:

- uninitialized variables that a debugger (sometimes) initializes to 0
- race conditions that don't show since the timing is now all different

Comment: +1 for the uninitialized variables, in particular for heap-allocated ones. When starting from a debugger you get the Windows Debug Heap, that pre-fills the heap-allocated memory with a particular pattern, while when staring "normally" you get pages with whatever is in it (typically zeros at program startup). A viable trick to see what's happening is to attach the debugger after the program has been started.